# Fire base notifications issues using IOS device

Tags: firebase, notifications, send

No APNS token was specified before fetching the FCM Token

No able to send the firebase notifications,
Error getting Firebase Token:

```
Error
Domain=com.google.fcm Code=505
"No APNS token specified before fetching FCM Token"
UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=No APNS token specified before fetching FCM Token}
```